# wp_logout_url redirect not working

Tags: redirect

```
logout_url = wp_logout_url( $custom_login_url);
echo "<a class='handler-login-link logout' href='{$logout_url}'>".__("Logout","pixel_framework")."</a>";
```

I have created a custom logout link that is supposed to redirect users to a custom login page (within the same domain).

Logout is working fine, but the redirection is not working at all. After logging out redirected to the default wp-login page.

I tried to inspect HTML behind the link it is like this:

```
https://example.com/?logout=0b2adca060&redirect_to=https://example.com/haendler-login/
```

Comment: That's wrong. The logout URL should be `https://example.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce=12345&redirect_to=` etc. (and the redirect-to URL urlencoded). i.e. it should use the login page to log out. Unless you have a different logout handler, and a logout_url filter from one of your plugins? I'd guess that logout handler doesn't support the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Use this logout link `<li class="signOut"><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a></li>`

And add below code in your functions.php file to redirect the user to the page you want:

```
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'auto_redirect_user_after_logout');
function auto_redirect_user_after_logout(){
  wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/haendler-login/' );
  exit();
}
```